# Locked User Account Mouse Settings

Tags: mouse, system-settings, xinput

I have an ubuntu build where I have a root account that only admins can access and then there is a user account with no root privileges that has autologin on and I have changed the permissions on most of the apps so users can't access them, including the settings app.

Now if a user wants to change their mouse settings they cannot because the settings app is not accessible. As a workaround I installed xinput-gui so that a user can change their mouse sensitivity there; just to find out that its not persistent and as soon as they reboot or probably even sign out it'll get reset.

Is there an easy way I can have the user change their mouse setting without using the traditional settings options built into ubuntu? Like another app or something I can install that saves those changes.

Currently using Ubuntu 20.04 with Gnome

Comment: Whats with the down likes? Its not a good question or what?

Comment: Sounds like a valid question to me. I vote to leave open.